# [SOLVED] ROS Hydro from source on Ubuntu 13.10 make error in qt_gui_cpp

Tags: ros, build, source, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit**  I gave up at the time and only installed ROS-COMMs, which went through fine.  But now that I have a need for the other tools, I decided to have a go at Desktop-Full again.  After a bunch of hurdles (some of which were probably self-induced) I was able to get it all working.  I can post my steps if there is interest (My log file is 5MB, so I will only do that if there is a demand.)

--

Hi,
I'm following the guide [Installing on Ubuntu from source](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source).
Whilst building the isolated install (using `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --make-args -d`), I got a cmake error while processing **qt_gui_cpp**.  I've posted the error message below:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
==> Building with env: '/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_cpp -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated in '/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.5") 
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.77
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.5+") 
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.4") 
-- Using default python: -python3.3
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Shiboken-1.1.2/ShibokenConfig.cmake:5 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Shiboken-1.1.2/ShibokenConfig-python3.3.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:6 (find_package)
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


-- Using default python: -python2.7
-- Shiboken binding generator available.
-- SIP binding generator available.
-- Python binding generators: shiboken;sip
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'qt_gui_cpp': 
  Command '/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_cpp -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp && /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/username/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_cpp -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated

Command failed, exiting.
```

My version of python is 2.7.5+, not 3.3.
I have the following ShibokenConfig files:  *.cpython-33m.cmake*, *-python2.7.cmake*, and *Version.cmake*
(Is this the source of the error?  Should I update my python? Or, does the version comparison (in ShebrokenConfigVersion.cmake) fail because of the '+' sign in my version number?)

Before building, I ran the command: `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y` to make sure I had everything needed: `#All required rosdeps installed successfully`. I have also been keeping my Ubuntu install up to date and I am using Gnome Flashback as my GUI, not Unity.

Has anyone else faced this problem, and how were you able to resolve it?

Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114386/%5Bsolved%5D-ros-hydro-from-source-on-ubuntu-13.10-make-error-in-qt_gui_cpp/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-01-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-04-21**:
I gave up at the time and installed ROS-COMMs.  Today I came back to this and was able to perform a full, working, desktop installation from source, after spending some time investigating the hurdles that were thrown up along the way.  If anyone is interested still, I can post the steps I performed.

**Comment by [soon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21990/soon/) on 2016-01-16**:
Yes, I am interested on it.
I hope this is not too late to ask you to post the steps that you had performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, here is a workaround that worked for me on Debian https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/issues/35#issuecomment-31562501

You can just make `sudo apt-get purge libshiboken-dev shiboken` from the terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1